# How to install UBUNTU MATE without another computer

Tags: raspbian, software-installation, ubuntu

I am using a raspberry pi 3 b (not b+) and I am looking to install Ubuntu MATE
I am currently running Raspbian but I have heard of Ubuntu MATE and wish to use it. 
However I have not another computer to install it with. I don't know a lot of terminal things, I know basic stuff but nothing like this. If someone can help and give me a guide on how to do this I would appreciate. I have a flash drive if I need one.

Comment: How did you install Raspbian? Use the same method.

Comment: I installed raspbian with NOOBS.

Comment: How do I flash?

Comment: Your answer avoids the question. How did you install NOOBS?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7bA9d6xgCN0

Answer (score 2):

you will need another sd card (plugged it to a reader in the USB port) and have downloaded the UbuntuMate image file already for this to work.

from the command promt

use

```
lsblk
```

to show the /dev/ of the sd card (unplug it and check again if you're unsure)

**using dd can destroy the image you have installed already if used incorrectly.**

first, unmount the drive with

```
sudo umount /dev/sd#?
```

second, write the image to the drive

```
sudo dd if=/path/to/ubuntu-mate.img of=/dev/sd#? bs=1M status=progress
```

now try out the new sd card in your pi